Relative path to the app folder to use shell_exec()
I use Laravel Sail by default. But now I have a problem that I want to use a standalone binary file for a service. Currently I have placed the file under app/Services/MyApp/bin/standAloneFile. the file is called via shell_exec(). In my Sail docker instance the whole path would be "/var/www/html/app/Services/MyApp/bin/standAloneFile" but on my server the path is completely different. That's why you should avoid working with absolute paths. So I wonder how to create a relative path to the app folder. Something like public_path(). The problem is the entry point of shell_exec().
public static function run(String $link, String $targetPath)
{
  $standAloneFile = '/var/www/html/app/Services/MyApp/bin/standAloneFile';
  return shell_exec('cd ../storage/app' . $targetPath . ' && ' .$standAloneFile .'  --link '. $link ');
}


You looking for app_path().
More path helpers are:

base_path()
config_path()
database_path()
mix()
public_path()
resource_path()
storage_path()

